# How can I start/stop a stop watch with only the spacebar?

Tags: java, swing, stopwatch

I want to start/stop a stop watch only using the spacebar. I already made the KeyListeners, and that they only get activated when you press/release the spacebar.

What I tried so far:

I tried creating a stopwatch class, which SHOULD calculate the time difference between me pressing space for the first time, and second time. I tried it as follows:

```
 public class Stopwatch {
    public Stopwatch(int i) {
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if(i%2==1){
            System.out.println("Timer Started at: " + time);
        }else{
            System.out.println("Timer stopped at: " + System.currentTimeMillis());

            System.out.println("Time diff: " + (time - System.currentTimeMillis()));
        }
    }
}
```

`int i` increases with every second spacebar press.

I know the problem here is that everytime I start this class, `time` is getting reset to System.currentTimeMillis() because I only press Spacebar. Thus the difference is always 0.

How can I change this so that I can somehow save the time I first pressed space?

Here is the class with the Keylisteners. Ignore the Scrambler class, it has nothing to do with my Problem.

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class StoppuhrFrame extends JFrame {

    JLabel time, scramble;

    public StoppuhrFrame() {

        time = new JLabel("00:00:00");
        time.setBounds(162, 45, 325, 80);
        time.setFont(new Font("Arial", 100, 80));
        add(time);

        scramble = new JLabel("Scramble: ");
        scramble.setBounds(165, 15, 370, 16);
        add(scramble);

        //Scrambler scrambler = new Scrambler(scramble);

        addKeyListener(new timer());
        setTitle("Cube Timer");
        setLayout(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);
        setSize(650, 270);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    int i = 1;
    public class timer implements KeyListener {
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent keyEvent) {

            if(keyEvent.getKeyCode()==32){
                new Stopwatch(i);
                i++;
            }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {

            if (arg0.getKeyCode() == 32) {
                if(i%2==0){
                    //new Scrambler(scramble);

                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you creating a new stop watch object every time the key is pressed? Also, you realize that `i` will never change once it is incremented the first time, because it is never going to be even when it is 1.

Comment: why not implement the stopwatch logic in the keyevent?

Comment: @realskeptic right, i changed it so it can now change.

Comment: *"Ignore the Scrambler class, it has nothing to do with my Problem."* It's easy to ignore, of you ***don't include it.*** For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I tried to add it as a comment but didn't let me to post the code.
Here is the example class I mentioned:

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class Example  implements KeyListener {

    private static long hitTime = -1;

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
        // This will allways return the time when first space bar was clicked
        long start = getHitTime();
        long actualTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        // In this case get the seconds..
        long diff = (actualTime - start) / 1000;

        System.out.println(String.format("TIme diff: %s", diff));
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    public synchronized static long getHitTime() {

        if (hitTime < 0) {
            hitTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
        return hitTime;
    }
}
```

You also dont need a stopwatch class as time will start passing after first key click (in this case not specific key was detected so any key hit will trigger the event), and will calculate the difference of time between first click and the last one in millis, I divide it by a thousand to get seconds between hits.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Make time a static attribute of the StopWatch user class initialized with a negative value (as i understand it may be the listener instance). Then apply a synchronized method to get the value of the time attribute (static syncrhonized to ensure thread-safe access to that var when updating it). and apply a singleton pattern nto update the value, considering that a value > 0 is possible when a space bar has been pressed:

```
private static long hitTime = -1;
//... 
public synchronized static long getFirstSpaceHitMillis() {
    if (hitTime < 0) {
        // this if ensures the variable will be only updated at first hit
        hitTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
    return hitTime;
}
```

In the StopWatch class the init time will be retrieved by a static call to the getFirstSpaceHitMillis method, so you'll get the time when first space was hit.

Hope this help, and sorry for not attaching a full implementation.

Comment: Thanks for answering, however no matter where I want to add `private static long hitTime  = -1`it always asks me to remove invalid modifiers. Where excatly do I have to add the code provided with having to deal with this?

Comment: This is an example class tested with java8 (but may work with previous versions of java, at least from java 1.5 as there are no use of new code in latest versions)

Comment: (a) If you want to add something, don't create a second answer, *add it to your original answer* which you can [edit].